# Convert datepart hour to local timezone

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2014

Is there a way to combine these two T-SQL queries? I'm using SQL Server 2014.

The goal is to be able to have the output of the first query in the converted local timezone as opposed (or in addition) to UTC time.  Basically looking to summarize records by hour in local timezone.

```sql
SELECT 
    DATEPART(HOUR, TimeUtc) AS UTCHour, Message, Application, 
    COUNT(Message) AS "Count"
FROM 
    [DB].[dbo].[TBL]
WHERE 
    timeutc BETWEEN '2022-10-21 00:00:00.000' AND '2022-10-21 23:59:59.000'
GROUP BY 
    DATEPART(HOUR, TimeUtc), Message, Application
HAVING 
    COUNT(Message) > 5
ORDER BY 
    UTCHour DESC, "Count" DESC
```

```sql
SELECT 
    CONVERT(datetime, SWITCHOFFSET(CONVERT(datetimeoffset, TimeUtc), DATENAME(TzOffset, SYSDATETIMEOFFSET()))) AS ColumnInLocalTime 
FROM 
    [DB].[dbo].[TBL]
WHERE 
    timeutc BETWEEN '2022-10-21 00:00:00.000' AND '2022-10-21 23:59:59.000'
```

**Example of current output:** (UTC Hour represents HH of the TimeUTC field)

| UTCHour | Message | Application | Count |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 23 | Request failed. | WebAppv101 | 86756309 |
| 23 | HTTP 500. | WebAppv101 | 8521 |
| 22 | Layer 8 Error. | WebAppv100 | 21 |
| 22 | ID10T Error. | WebAppv101 | 10 |

**Example of desired output:**
(basically 23:00 UTC = 16:00 PDT, I am not concerned about the formatting, ie 16:00 vs 4PM, etc. as long as the output is in PDT).

| PDTHour | Message | Application | Count |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 16 | Request failed. | WebAppv101 | 86756309 |
| 16 | HTTP 500. | WebAppv101 | 8521 |
| 15 | Layer 8 Error. | WebAppv100 | 21 |
| 15 | ID10T Error. | WebAppv101 | 10 |

Comment: `where timeutc between '2022-10-21 00:00:00.000' and '2022-10-21 23:59:59.000'` is just a bad idea since there is all kinds of bad mojo you're inviting trying to be precise about the "end" of a day (and that changes dramatically if the column or parameter changes types). Try `where timeutc >= '20221021' and timeutc < '20221022'`.

Comment: Next, describe what result you're getting now using the query you have, how it's wrong, and what you expect instead. We can't see your data and we have no idea what time zone you expect or what you want any of the output to look like. And it might not be wise to rely on `SYSDATETIMEOFFSET()` since your server could move, could be changed to UTC (or some other time zone than the current one), the code may be deployed to a different server, etc. etc.

Comment: Also consider how you want the code to handle corner cases, such as the date range you're looking at is in DST (or not) and the current date is the opposite. Or the range _straddles_ a DST changeover.

Comment: @RhythmWasaLurker thank you for the provided information.  Right now my output shows the UTC Hour value and I would like it to be displayed in PDT Hour format. Other than that, I am happy with the results of the first query.  This is a query I run manually and I'm not concerned about the precision or deployability as I am constantly modifying it  on the fly to suit whatever I am looking for.

Comment: Any chance you can move to SQL Server 2016 or newer? SQL Server 2014 reached end of life three years ago, and 2016 introduced `AT TIME ZONE` which I think would make your time a whole lot easier.

Comment: @RhythmWasaLurker eventually, but no timeline for this upgrade at the moment.  If this is not easily doable in SQL Server 2014, no biggie.  I figured it didn't hurt to ask but I can live with the current results I am getting.

Comment: It's not impossible, but I'm still trying to understand exactly what you want (which is why sample data and expected output is better than just describing it). For example, I'm not sure what `in PDT Hour format` means. Building a minimal reproducible example will really help.

Comment: @RhythmWasaLurker, I added a couple tables of example output.  Hopefully this example helps.  Basically I am using this query to summarize error messages by UTC Hour, that is the HH value of the UTC time.

Comment: So always Pacific Time, but do you want the output to reflect the UTC hour according to the day/time the query runs, or the day/time for the particular row? The problem is you might be running the query 5 minutes after DST changeover, so data from the previous hour is going to be missing or doubled. (This is kind of why we tend to run servers in UTC and pull data out of SQL Server in UTC, if we want the end user to see it in their time zone then we perform that translation on the client.)

Comment: So if SQL Server were to take you literally and convert UTC time to PDT... is it acceptable to return a `null` when PST is in effect? This seems like a strange request. Generally the drive from Ops and SRE teams is for all systems to record and correlate events in UTC so that you don't have to deal with holes in local time or double-ups during DT/ST and ST/DT transitions. UTC everywhere helps to maintain a certain level of sanity.

Comment: @RhythmWasaLurker the time for the particular row.

Comment: @AlwaysLearning it's just for readability of the output when I run the query.  We commonly used the SELECT statement in the 2nd query to output our local time.  These are just manual queries we use to pull information from our logging database to quantify the errors. So ideally I could run slightly different query for PST.  But it's not that serious.  I feel like maybe I should have kept this question to myself TBH lol.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```sql
select dateadd(MINUTE,DATEPART(TZ,SYSDATETIMEOFFSET()),sysutcdatetime());
```

This will return a datetime field in the current timezone, which is calculated from the `sysutcdatetime`, whith the addition of the number of minutes which is retruned from the `sysdatetimeoffset`.

NOTE: I do not know if the functions `sysutcdatetime` and `sysdatetimeoffset` are available in SQL Server 2014.

When you think this functionality is too long to type (or to remember), you can create a Function for this:

```sql
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[UTCtoLocale] 
(
    @p1 datetime
)
RETURNS datetime
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @Result datetime

    SELECT @Result = dateadd(MINUTE,DATEPART(TZ,SYSDATETIMEOFFSET()),@p1);

    RETURN @Result

END
GO
```

After this, `SELECT dbo.UTCtoLocale(sysutcdatetime());` should return the local time;

P.S. The name of this function is chosen, when you know a better name, then feel free to change it.

Your SQL query using this function:

```sql
SELECT 
    DATEPART(HOUR, dbo.UTCtoLocale(TimeUtc)) AS LocalHour, Message, Application, 
    COUNT(Message) AS "Count"
FROM 
    [DB].[dbo].[TBL]
WHERE 
    dbo.UTCtoLocale(timeutc) BETWEEN '2022-10-21 00:00:00.000' AND '2022-10-21 23:59:59.000'
GROUP BY 
    DATEPART(HOUR, dbo.UTCtoLocale(TimeUtc)), Message, Application
HAVING 
    COUNT(Message) > 5
ORDER BY 
    LocalHour DESC, "Count" DESC
```

This function will get the results based on the local date '2022-10-21', your original was looking at the utc-date for this day.

Comment: This works great, and has the added benefit of using local time in the Where clause!  Thanks a bunch!

Comment: I don't think this works the way you think. It's going to apply the delta between UTC and local time _today_ even for dates that are on the other side of a DST change. If Pacific is 7 hours during the summer, and 8 hours during the winter, you're going to apply one or the other to _all of the dates in your table_ even if some of them observed DST and some of them didn't. `SYSDATETIMEOFFSET()` only takes into account _the offset right now_ regardless of what you're passing in as `@p1`.

Comment: ...but I suppose you'll find that out when all of your data starts changing after the next DST change. You'll basically be saying "apply _today's_ offset (during standard time) to last week's data (that observed DST)."

Comment: @RhythmWasaLurker I appreciate your explanation.  This is a caviat that I will keep in mind.  This is a query that I run manually for troubleshooting.  Most times I am only looking at a window of only a couple of hours.  Many times the pattern of errors is more important than the actual time.  I can always run the original query that I posted if/when I run into the situation you are describing.  For me the tradeoff of readability is worth putting up with the nuances of the edge cases that likely won't matter in my use case regardless.

Comment: @philipgonzales3 Fair, but my disclaimers are also useful for future readers who come across this answer and thinks it solves the problem for their scenario when maybe they are looking to implement a permanent solution, that looks at more than a range within the last day, etc. Most readers might be lulled into that function accepting any date, past or future, and having it return the right offset _for that date_. It only happens to work when the date you pass is in the same offset as right now (admittedly that's only important for time zones that observe DST).